# "Explorer" vs. "explorator"

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the difference between words **explorer** and **explorator**? (Both seem to mean *one who explores something*.)

Answer (score 2):

Explorator is not one would call a word, or at least one in regular use. See this [google n-gram comparison](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=explorer,explorator&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) of these words' usage.

Explorator is likely used as an intentional corruption of the word explorer to suggest the image of someone who is "an explorer, but something more than that." Explorator is closer to the words "Exploration" and "Exploratory".